# Luigi task finishes instantly even thought I doesn't run anything

Tags: python, luigi

Result of task is successful even thought there is no output.

Luigi says:
Did not run any tasks
This progress looks :) because there were not tasks or missing external dependencies.

All previous required tasks run fine and the result is not empty when I run them separately.
Regarding failing task - I can trigger it by hacking complete method to return always False.

All help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you provide code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.